# Ventilation - Push system into Pull system, what can happen

Tags: pressure, flow, air

this is my first question so please go easy on me.
I have a system where it pulls air out of a sealed box at ~500l/min (this sealed box has a requested pressure of 10Pa, in case it is relevant).
The fan is located at the outlet of the air, hence the pull, and is connected to an HVAC stack. The requested flow on the HVAC stack is 100l/min-500l/min and the fan is located at least several meters from the connection between the 2 systems.

My question is this - If the pull flow rate is the same as the push flow rate what is the effect?
500+500=~1000l/min
500 and 500=500l/min
or something else?
Also if the Pull flow rate is lower or higher, what is the overall effect?

I have been trying to read and find calculations for this but am struggling so I am hoping I can find my answers here.
Thank you in advance
Rick